# Starting localstack fails - missing termios

Tags: termios, localstack

termios appears to be a Python module required for localstack.  Installing on my Windows machine using pip fails.  Further research reveals this is only available on UNIX systems.  What is the Windows workaround?  I prefer to not go the Docker route - hyperthreading issues if I remember correctly.

My current environment:

Windows 10 (64-bit)

make 3.79.1

python 3.6.1

pip 19.1

npm 5.6.0

java 1.8.0_211

javac 1.8.0_45

mvn 3.6.1

```
> python localstack start
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "localstack", line 30, in 
    from localstack.utils import cli
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\localstack\utils\cli.py", line 4, in 
    from localstack.services import infra
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\localstack\services\infra.py", line 20, in 
    from localstack.utils import common, persistence
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\localstack\utils\common.py", line 7, in 
    import pty
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\pty.py", line 11, in 
    import tty
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tty.py", line 5, in 
    from termios import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'

Answer (score 0):

You should use docker to install localstack.   It is their preferred method.  That said, if you download the [Commandeer Desktop App](https://getcommandeer.com), it has an install process that uses docker under the hood and has a nice UI for managing LocalStack.

[image]